# Android Cocos2d MoveTo Actions

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone

I'm a complete noob to Cocos2D and Java, so please forgive my ignorance but I am very keen to learn!

By way of learning, I'm creating a simple app that displays a collection of images (stored in an array) and then make them all move to a touch location.

I can't quite get the hang of actions and MoveTo because in the For loop below only the last image in the array moves.

```
public boolean ccTouchesMoved(MotionEvent e){
    CGPoint touchLocation = CCDirector.sharedDirector().convertToGL(CGPoint.ccp(e.getX(), e.getY()));
    CCMoveTo imgMove = CCMoveTo.action(2f, touchLocation);
        for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length; ++i){
            imgs[i].runAction(imgMove); 
        };
    return true;
};
```

Also, the image doesn't always move on every touch (it's a bit random) and I get this error in the log:

```
CCActionManager removeAction: target not found
```

I assume I need to add some sort of end-of-action command?  I also don't understand why only the last image in the array moves and not the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `runAction` method, a reference to the object to be animated is stored in the action object, so if you run the same action object on each iteration, only the last image will keep stored.

To solve this, you only need to create a `CCMoveTo` action for every image in your array. Also, `++i` increments the variable `i` before using it in the first iteration, so you're skipping the first element of your array.

The code would look like this.-

```
public boolean ccTouchesMoved(MotionEvent e){
    CGPoint touchLocation = CCDirector.sharedDirector().convertToGL(CGPoint.ccp(e.getX(), e.getY()));        
        for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
            CCMoveTo imgMove = CCMoveTo.action(2f, touchLocation);
            imgs[i].runAction(imgMove); 
        };
    return true;
};
```

By the way, I believe *cocos2d for android* is no longer under development, if you're learning, I'd recommend going for [cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) or [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/).

Comment: Thanks, such a simple fix!  I didn't realise Cocos2D was no longer in development for Android but that would explain why it's so hard to find guides (I've been trying to follow guides for iOS Cocos2D).

Comment: Glad it helped :) I guess you'll be fine with cocos2d-android if you don't try anything 'out of common', but you'll probably miss something working in more advanced stuff. Anyway, best of lucks!